# How to merge two double joins in ActiveQuery

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, firebird

I have two double joins (I believe that's what they would be considered) and it just seems awfully slow to do them separately.  I know there are debates as to whether or not an individual query is quicker than multiple queries and vice versa but I am willing to try anything.

Here are my existing statements:

```
line_stops = OpsHeader.joins(
        ops_stop_rec: :driver_header
      )
    .select(
        :pbbname,
        :pb_net_rev,
        :ops_driver1,
        :pb_id,
        :ops_stop_id,
        :dh_first_name,
        :dh_last_name,
        :ops_delivered_time
      )
      .where(
        :ops_stop_rec => {
            ops_arrive_time: params[:startDate] .. params[:endDate]
        })


    line_items = OpsHeader.joins(
        ops_stop_rec: :ops_line_items
      ).select(
        :pbbname,
        :opl_amount,
        :pb_id,
        :ops_type,
        :ops_stop_id,
        :ops_order_id,
        :ops_driver1,
        :ops_delivered_time
      )
      .where(
        :ops_stop_rec => {
            ops_arrive_time: params[:startDate] .. params[:endDate]
        }
      )
```

Just for reference, I am pulling these from an old Firebird Database and the server hardware is not necessarily quick either, so there may be more at play than I am thinking.  Also, I have to data manipulation on top of that before I serve it to the client.

Anyway, here are my associations:

```
class OpsHeader < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :pb_bill
  belongs_to :pb_master

  has_many :ops_stop_rec, foreign_key: 'ops_order_id'

  self.table_name = 'OPS_HEADER'
  self.primary_key = 'pb_id'
end
```

```
class OpsStopRec < ApplicationRecord
  #belongs_to :ops_order
  #belongs_to :ops_im_equip
  belongs_to :ops_header, foreign_key: 'pb_id'
  belongs_to :driver_header, foreign_key: 'ops_driver1'

  has_many :ops_line_items, foreign_key: 'opl_stop_id'

  self.table_name = 'OPS_STOP_REC'
  self.primary_key = 'ops_stop_id'


end
```

```
class OpsLineItem < ApplicationRecord
  #belongs_to :opl_order
  #belongs_to :opl_stop

  belongs_to :ops_stop_rec, foreign_key: 'ops_stop_id'

  self.table_name = 'OPS_LINE_ITEMS'
  self.primary_key = 'opl_stop_id'
end
```

```
class DriverHeader < ApplicationRecord
  #belongs_to :dh_paythru
  has_many :ops_stop_rec, foreign_key: 'ops_driver1'
  
  self.table_name = 'DRIVER_HEADER'
  self.primary_key = 'dh_id'
end
```

Comment: "old Firebird Database" - how old? what is database version? can you clone it to development environment and upgrade server to firebird 2.5 ? "server hardware is not necessarily quick" Groton/Interbase/Firebird were conceived in 1970-s when RAM was ultra-expensive and ultra-scarce. You may consider optimized, RAM-relaxed Firebird configurations and articles on manual optimizations on ib-aid.com

Comment: can you run this query on the server of yours? -  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=firebird_3.0 - if my memory is okay it would work starting with FB 2.0 but fail on FB 1.x

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're looking for is a [union operator](https://firebirdsql.org/refdocs/langrefupd20-select.html#langrefupd20-union). There is [a gem](https://github.com/brianhempel/active_record_union) which can handle it for you.

Or try using using two left outer joins and add an OR condition.

Comment: While those will help with the merger, do you think they'll help performance?

Comment: Not necessarily, depends on the data you have. Left outer join with the or condition should be faster than a union because a union is basically doing two queries internally in the DB. Which is still better than doing two separate queries because you save one roundtrip to the DB. But it's probably a marginal improvement since it's just one roundtrip.

BTW it's better to do a UNION ALL and then apply a DISTINCT to it instead of just doing a UNION. 

So i'd start with a left outer join first because it seems to be the most promising.

Comment: @AttemptedMastery if you would want to optimize performance than i think you would have to jump from high abstractions of ORM and AR down to lower level of SQL, etc. You would have to maybe optimize database structure and to find optimal queries in plain SQL, and after than you would climb back to ORM/AR abstractions and try to coerce them to generate queries resembling one you handcrafted in SQL IDE. In particular, your question `do you think they'll help performance` can not be answered without real information about DB scheme, data and execution path Firebird takes